# Code: BadRequest Message: Category 'allLogs' is not supported

Tags: azure-cli

Trying to create diagnostic-settings via CLI but getting error when i specify the logs category AllLogs

```
az monitor diagnostic-settings create --name KeyVault-Diagnostics --resource /subscriptions/xxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/xxxxx/flexibleServers/xxx --logs    "[{\"category\": \"AllLogs\",\"enabled\": true}]" --storage-account /subscriptions/xxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxx/providers/xx/storageAccounts/xxxx
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use categoryGroup:AllLogs

```
 az monitor diagnostic-settings create --name test --resource /subscriptions/subid/resourcegroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/cluster --logs "[{'categoryGroup':'AllLogs','enabled':true}]" --storage-account /subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/str
```